# Does Silverlight 4.0 support bindings in a style setter?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to port an application from WPF to Silverlight but it fails on some very simple binding.

I have the following simple example:

```
    <ListBox >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding X}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas></Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       </ListBox>
```

However, Silverlight parsing crashes.
However, if I replace the binding with a constant, things are OK:

```
    <ListBox >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="3"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas></Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this workaround:

http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nop it doesn't provide that (still)